# google maps run before i fetch my data from firebase hence it crashed

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

Im fetching lat and lng from firebase but it runs after onMapReady hence when i pass coords to onMapReady it crashed beacause arraylist has nothing

I want to run onMapReady after my data is loaded in my arrays

```
private void loadMapPins(){
    Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HOSTELS").orderByChild("LOCATION_ID").equalTo(hostelID);
    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot childsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            LatAndLng latAndLng = childsnap.child("MAP_LOCATION").getValue(LatAndLng.class);
            lat.add(String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLATITUDE()));
            lng.add(String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLONGITUDE() ));
            Log.d("latitudess", "onDataChange: "+String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLATITUDE()));
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}





@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat.get(0), lng.get(0));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,15f));




}

 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    loadMapPins();

   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat.get(0)), Float.parseFloat(lng.get(0)));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,15f));
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the on map ready inside on datachange so that whenever i got dta onMapReady runs after that only

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HOSTELS").orderByChild("LOCATION_ID").equalTo(hostelID);
    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot childsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                LatAndLng latAndLng = childsnap.child("MAP_LOCATION").getValue(LatAndLng.class);
                lat.add(String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLATITUDE()));
                lng.add(String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLONGITUDE() ));
                Log.d("latitudess", "onDataChange: "+String.valueOf(latAndLng.getLATITUDE()));
            }

            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat.get(0)), Float.parseFloat(lng.get(0)));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,15f));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to asynchronous actions:

1. Loading the data that is displayed in the map
2. Loading the map that displays the data

Since the map is dependent on the data, you should only start loading the map once the data is available. I can't show the code of how to do this, but you'll need to make the call that wires up whatever calls `onMapReady` from within `onDataChange` with something like:

```
mapRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HOSTELS").child(hostelID).child("MAP_LOCATION");
mapRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Inside_location inside_location=dataSnapshot.getValue(Inside_location.class);
        lat.add(Double.valueOf(inside_location.getLATITUDE()) );
        lng.add(Double.valueOf(inside_location.getLONGITUDE())) ;

        // TODO: start loading the map based on the lat and lng
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wait google map for load to do actions over it.
In your case, call loadMapPins in onMapReady and your current onMapReady code move to the end of onDataChange method.

Comment: i tried it but still it crashes im calling loadmappins inside onmapready

Comment: We need logs in order you help you. Please, share it on your post.

Comment: wait i have changed the code a little can you see again but still its not working

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teepe.teepe, PID: 19923
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.teepe.teepe.insideHostelList.onMapReady(insideHostelList.java:468)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)